# How to load resource file from dependency jar?

Tags: java, android, resources

I have a Java project and a resource file (in src/main/resources). In this project I have a block of code that loads the file using getResourceAsStream from a class loader. Using this project as a dependency in another java project works fine.

When I use this as dependency for my Android project, this resource file cannot be found. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use target jar classloader like this

ClassInOtherJar.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("NewFilename.xml")

Comment: Doesn't work. Also note that the code that tries to get the resource is inside my dependency

Comment: @vagcore did you figure it out?